# Unable to draw a polygon due to "The feature cannot be added..."

Tags: qgis, layers, intersection

> The feature cannot be added because it's geometry collapsed due to
>   intersection avoidance.

see also https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cA1N.png

What happended: Let's say I have 2 layers. To the first I enabled the snapping tool with avoid Intersections. So far so good.

Now I added a polygon to the layer 2. That layer has nothing enabled in the Snapping tool. But as you can see from the error above, it's broken. So I'm not able to create a polygon on top of the layer 1. Is this intended? I mean where does the avoid intersection option make sense if this is intended?

This is more a general question, because with disabling the avoid intersection I was able to create a polygon on layer 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find your solution at [Here](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/7968) that says

> The above message shows not only when a feature cannot be digitized because it would be removed because of the "avoid intersection" option.It shows also when digitizing a polygon adjacent to another one that has errors. This message is very misleading in this cases. The user should be warned that the polygon cannot be digitized because the one being used to "clip" the overlapped part has errors.

Comment: Yeah so it's intended overall. But for what using that feature? I mean I just had it enabled for testing and forgot disabling it.